# Exception(AbstractPostgreSQLDriver->convertException) in Doctrine is for insertion of data in postgresql (Using symfony)

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table called user in postgresql. Now when I want to create a record in this table I am getting an exception:

> AbstractPostgreSQLDriver->convertException('An exception occurred while executing \'INSERT INTO user (user_id, organization_id, client_id, username, password, type, lname, fname, init, email, date, time, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)\' with params [6, 1, 1, "kmr", "kmr12345", "Individual", "c", "a", "b", "abc@gmail.com", "2017-07-30", "16:07:46", "active"]:SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"LINE 1: INSERT INTO user (user_id, organization_id, client_id, usern... ^', object(PDOException))

My table schema is :

```
user_id           integer    
organization_id   integer    
client_id         integer    
username          character varying(255)     
password          character varying(255)     
type              character varying(255)     
lname             character varying(255)     
fname             character varying(255)     
init              character varying(255)     
email             character varying(255)     
date              character varying(255)     
time              character varying(255)     
status            character varying(255)
```

My symfony's parameters.yml is like;

```
parameters:
  database_host: localhost
  database_port: 5432
  database_name: task_management
  database_user: postgres
  database_password: 123456
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: null
  mailer_password: null
  secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

When I am using MySql db (definitely with a different configuration), same PHP code is working.

```
$user = new User();

$user->setUserId(1);
$user->setOrganizationId(1);
$user->setClientId(1);
$user->setUserName('k');
$user->setType('Individual');
$user->setPassword('kmr12345');
$user->setFirstName('a');
$user->setLastName('b');
$user->setInitial('c');
$user->setEmail('abc@gmail.com');
$user->setDate(date('Y-m-d'));
$user->setTime(date('H:m:s'));
$user->setStatus('active');

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

return $user->getUserId();
```

But in case of postgresql I am constantly getting this error.

Any help will be great for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide the Doctrine mapping in your Entity, but I think this is where your problem lies. Take a short example of a User-entity:

```
 <?php

 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="user")
  */
 class User
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="username", length=50)
      */
     private $username;

     // ... remaining properties and getters/setters
}
```

I assume your entity looks something like that. The problem is the Table-annotation. you might not even have set a name, but then it will default to your class name, meaning Doctrine will assume something like above.

The problem with this is that `user` is a reserved word in sql and therefore needs to be escaped. So it should look something like:

```
@ORM\Table(name="`user`")
```

It seems MySQL is more forgiving with this than PostgreSQL, but in every case you use a reserved word you should escape it. This is also mentioned in the Doctrine Documentation [Basic Mapping-section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words)

> Sometimes it is necessary to quote a column or table name because of reserved word conflicts. Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically, because it leads to more problems than it would solve. Quoting tables and column names needs to be done explicitly using ticks in the definition.

You can find a list of reserved words in PostgreSQL in it's documentation, in the [SQL Keywords-Appendix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Though I already solved it. The error should show more detail.

Comment: The error message is just passed on from the database. Since the message  "syntax error at or near ..." is pretty generic, I don't think Doctrine can reasonably infer what the error was and help out by enriching it. I know that's a bit crummy, especially since this is a pretty common trap, but I wouldn't wait for this to improve.

Comment: Here is the syntax if you use attributes: `#[ORM\Table(name: '\`user\`')]`